# Android: How to update Background color of Activity when Thread completes

Tags: android

In the xml i have given background image for my root Layout. In a program I want to replace the image with black color after the background data completes. intention is user will see the progress bass and the background with company logo. but i cannot populate the list on top of the background image as it is not readable. so I want to apply a black color after data populates.

Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

get instance of root layout inside activity and update background color when thread completed .
lets assume its a linear layout :

```
LinearLayout rootLayout ;
```

in

```
onCreate()
{

rootLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootLayout); //whatever you given in xml 

}
```

when thread completes

runOnUIThread(new Runnable(
run()
{
    rootLayout.setBackgroudResource(R.color.black) 
}
));

//please verify typos n syntax

hope you already added black `<color black>#000000</color>` in res/values

Comment: Question here is, I want to do rootLayout.setBackgroudResource(R.color.black)  after thread completes. how will i sent a notification to UI without using Asynctask as I already implemented in lot of classes and difficult to change all the code now.

Comment: i through by complete the tread you meant now you are back to UI thread . anyway hope edited code will help . although you can use handler or Async task as well ,but this is the shortest aproach suilable for such small UI modifications